# Slow down an html anchor link

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, scroll, anchor

I've seen this pretty cool feature on other websites but I can't seem to find it myself.

I want to make a link to a different part of the page through an anchor tag scroll and not just jump to the desired id. I suppose a javascript file could help or maybe a css transition but I dont know that transition element it would be.

```
<a href="#bottom">scroll to bottom</a>

<p id="bottom">bottom</p>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Im on mobile so the code embedded and I can't change it...but im sure you get what i mean.

Comment: [jQuery.ScrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html)

Comment: How would I use that? As an onclick function and just put an id in like this onclck="jQuery.ScrollTo(bottom)"

Comment: Why don't you read the page linked on how to use it? It's pretty well explained there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since nobody really answered this question before I'll answer with my discovery for people who need it.

All you have to do is normal anchor links like this

```
<a href="#bottom">scroll to bottom</a>

<p id="bottom">bottom</p>
```

then add this Javascript Code and if you need to change anything, look at the javascript comments

```
<script>
    $(function() {

        function filterPath(string) {
            return string
            .replace(/^\//,'')
            .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/,'')
            .replace(/\/$/,'');
        }

        var locationPath = filterPath(location.pathname);
        var scrollElem = scrollableElement('html', 'body');

        // Any links with hash tags in them (can't do ^= because of fully qualified URL potential)
        $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {

            // Ensure it's a same-page link
            var thisPath = filterPath(this.pathname) || locationPath;
            if (  locationPath == thisPath
                && (location.hostname == this.hostname || !this.hostname)
                && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {

                    // Ensure target exists
                    var $target = $(this.hash), target = this.hash;
                    if (target) {

                        // Find location of target
                        var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
                        $(this).click(function(event) {

                            // Prevent jump-down
                            event.preventDefault();

                            // Animate to target
                            $(scrollElem).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 400, function() {

                                // Set hash in URL after animation successful
                                location.hash = target;

                            });
                        });
                    }
            }

        });

        // Use the first element that is "scrollable"  (cross-browser fix?)
        function scrollableElement(els) {
            for (var i = 0, argLength = arguments.length; i <argLength; i++) {
                var el = arguments[i],
                $scrollElement = $(el);
                if ($scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0) {
                    return el;
                } else {
                    $scrollElement.scrollTop(1);
                    var isScrollable = $scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0;
                    $scrollElement.scrollTop(0);
                    if (isScrollable) {
                        return el;
                    }
                }
            }
            return [];
        }

    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 11):

A bit of css did the job for me:

```
html { scroll-behavior: smooth; }
```

I found more useful information here:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/